# Possible to copy Clipboard text/html mimetype to text/plain in javascript?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Let's say I have `text/html` that has been generated from a copy-to-clipboard event (such as `document.execCommand`).

Is there a way to copy that data into the `text/plain` mimetype without losing the `text/html` data? If so, how could this be done? Note that I have text/html data currently in the copy clipboard and it's not an option to write both at the same time.

Comment: "and it's not an option to write both at the same time." What does that mean? Why can't you write both at the same time? When do you want to write that data to the clipboard then? And why does it need to be in the clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is probably to handle it at the copying directly. Since `text/html` should be set only when copying from the Selection and not from inputs, we can get the markup through the Range API, and overwrite the data of our copy event.

```js
addEventListener( "copy", (evt) => {
  const selection = getSelection();
  if( selection.isCollapsed ) return;
  evt.preventDefault();
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  const data_as_html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( range.cloneContents() );
  evt.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", data_as_html);
  evt.clipboardData.setData("text/html", data_as_html);
} );
```

```html
<p>
  <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">copy</span><span style="color:green;font-weight:thinner"> this</span>
  <span style="color:blue"> text</span>
</p>
<div contenteditable>Paste here as rich-text</div>
<textarea cols="30" rows="10">Paste here as markup</textarea>
```

Now OP said they can't do it at that time, for I don't know what reasons.
This means they need to be able to read the content of the clipboard, and for this, they need the user's approval, either through the Clipboard API's Permissions, or by handling a `"paste"` event.

However, it seems no browser really supports reading anything else than `plain/text` from the Clipboard API, which leaves us only the paste event:

```js
btn.onclick = (evt) => {
  addEventListener( "paste", (evt) => {
    const data_as_html = evt.clipboardData.getData("text/html");
    if( data_as_html ) {

    }
    addEventListener("copy", (evt) => {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", data_as_html);
      evt.clipboardData.setData("text/html", data_as_html);
    }, { once: true } );
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }, { once: true } );
  document.execCommand("paste");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">convert clipboard content to markup</button><br>
<p>
  <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">copy</span><span style="color:green;font-weight:thinner"> this</span>
  <span style="color:blue"> text</span>
</p>
<div contenteditable>Paste here as rich-text</div>
<textarea cols="30" rows="10">Paste here as markup</textarea>
```